# React loop over an object with array

Tags: reactjs

```
data = [
  {
    "2017-08-09": [
      "09:00",
      "09:30",
      "10:00",
      "10:30",
      "11:00",
      "11:30",
      "13:00",
      "13:30",
      "14:00",
      "14:30",
      "15:00",
      "15:30",
      "16:00",
      "16:30"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to map over this array of objects and display info as follows:

```
Date 2017-08-09 
available hours 
  09:00
  09:30
  10:00
       ...
```

I'm having trouble looping over this data structure,

https://codesandbox.io/s/qzrvlvx9nj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your link. I did not use lodash, just nested `map()` calls. I first map through the initial array, and within each object I grab all the keys of that object. After that, I map through the keys of the object, and finally one last `map()` through the times of each date.

You can refer the below code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "2017-08-09": [
      "09:00",
      "09:30",
      "10:00",
      "10:30",
      "11:00",
      "11:30",
      "13:00",
      "13:30",
      "14:00",
      "14:30",
      "15:00",
      "15:30",
      "16:00",
      "16:30"
    ]
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>JS Map</h2>
        {
          data.map(item => {
            
            return Object.keys(item).map(date => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1>{date}</h1>
                  {item[date].map(time => {
                    return <h3>{time}</h3>
                  })}
                </div>
              )
            })
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your explanation

Answer (score 5):

Data is an array of objects, so first you need use map on it, after that to run loop on object property values, first use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the array, after that again use loop on available times array.

Write it like this:

```
{
    data.map((el,i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            Available Dates:
            {
                Object.entries(el).map(([key, value], j) => (
                    <div key={j}>
                        {key}
                        Available Times:
                        {
                            value.map(t => <div key={t}> {t} </div>)
                        }
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    ))
}
```

Check the working code : https://codesandbox.io/s/24n524ynz0

Working Snippet:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "2017-08-09": [
      "09:00",
      "09:30",
      "10:00",
      "10:30",
      "11:00",
      "11:30",
      "13:00",
      "13:30",
      "14:00",
      "14:30",
      "15:00",
      "15:30",
      "16:00",
      "16:30"
    ]
  }
];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>JS Map</h2>
    {
      data.map((el,i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          Available Date:
          {
            Object.entries(el).map(([key, value], j) => (
              <div>
                {key}
                Available Time:
                {
                  value.map(t => <div>{t}</div>)
                }
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```