# I am building a react native app and I want to display data from an api but the api would change its structure depending on date provided

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

one type of response would be this:-

```
{
    "Stages": [
        {
            "Sid": "13182",
            "Snm": "Women's Premier League",
            "Scd": "womens-premier-league",
            "Cnm": "India",
            "Csnm": "India",
            "Ccd": "india",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "902264",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "902264",
                        "12": "SBTE_28574291"
                    },
                    "Media": {
                        "12": [
                            {
                                "eventId": "Sky Sports",
                                "provider": "ABELSON",
                                "type": "TV_CHANNEL",
                                "allowedCountries": [
                                    "GB",
                                    "IE"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "UP Warriorz",
                            "ID": "248138",
                            "Abr": "UPW"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Royal Challengers Bangalore Women",
                            "ID": "248140",
                            "Abr": "ROY"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "NS",
                    "Esid": 1,
                    "EpsL": "Not started",
                    "Epr": 0,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "ErnInf": "Match 13",
                    "Et": 100,
                    "EtTx": "Womens Domestic Twenty20",
                    "ECo": "Teams will be announced at the toss",
                    "TPa": 0,
                    "TCho": 0,
                    "Esd": 20230315193000,
                    "Ese": 20230315193000,
                    "Exd": 1,
                    "EO": 524295,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "39",
            "Snm": "World Cup League 2",
            "Scd": "world-cup-league-2",
            "Cnm": "ICC Men's One-Day World Cup",
            "Csnm": "ICC Men's One-Day World Cup",
            "Ccd": "icc-mens-one-day-world-cup",
            "Scu": 1,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "894448",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "894448",
                        "12": "SBTE_28574320"
                    },
                    "Media": {
                        "12": [
                            {
                                "eventId": "368052",
                                "provider": "IMG",
                                "type": "LIVE_STREAMING",
                                "allowedCountries": [
                                    "GB",
                                    "IE",
                                    "NL"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 234,
                    "Tr2C1": 236,
                    "Tr1CW1": 7,
                    "Tr2CW1": 4,
                    "Tr1CO1": 50.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 38.4,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Papua New Guinea",
                            "ID": "86152",
                            "Abr": "PAP"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "United Arab Emirates",
                            "ID": "86127",
                            "Abr": "UNI"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "FT",
                    "Esid": 6,
                    "EpsL": "Finished",
                    "Epr": 2,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "ErnInf": "Match 128",
                    "Et": 120,
                    "EtTx": "ODI",
                    "ECo": "United Arab Emirates win by 6 wickets",
                    "TPa": 1,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230315084500,
                    "Ese": 20230315084500,
                    "Exd": 1,
                    "EO": 6291557,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "12979",
            "Snm": "Pakistan Super League",
            "Scd": "super-league",
            "Cnm": "Pakistan",
            "Csnm": "Pakistan",
            "Ccd": "pakistan",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "916122",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "916122",
                        "12": "SBTE_28567598"
                    },
                    "Media": {
                        "12": [
                            {
                                "eventId": "Sky Sports",
                                "provider": "ABELSON",
                                "type": "TV_CHANNEL",
                                "allowedCountries": [
                                    "GB",
                                    "IE"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Lahore Qalandars",
                            "ID": "86143",
                            "Abr": "LAH"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Multan Sultans",
                            "ID": "86139",
                            "Abr": "MUL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "NS",
                    "Esid": 1,
                    "EpsL": "Not started",
                    "Epr": 0,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "ErnInf": "Qualifier",
                    "Et": 100,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic Twenty20",
                    "ECo": "Teams will be announced at the toss",
                    "TPa": 0,
                    "TCho": 0,
                    "Esd": 20230315193000,
                    "Ese": 20230315193000,
                    "Exd": 1,
                    "EO": 524295,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "10935",
            "Snm": "Marsh Sheffield Shield",
            "Scd": "marsh-sheffield-shield",
            "Cnm": "Australia",
            "Csnm": "Australia",
            "Ccd": "australia",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "723835",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "723835",
                        "12": "SBTE_28555865"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 479,
                    "Tr2C1": 180,
                    "Tr1CW1": 7,
                    "Tr2CW1": 6,
                    "Tr1CD1": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 140.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 50.0,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Tasmania",
                            "ID": "86292",
                            "Abr": "TAS"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Queensland",
                            "ID": "86295",
                            "Abr": "QUE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 133,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 2",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Queensland trail Tasmania by 299 runs with 4 wickets remaining",
                    "Ebat": 2,
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 2,
                    "Esd": 20230314050000,
                    "Ese": 20230317050000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "723836",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "723836",
                        "12": "SBTE_28555866"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 134,
                    "Tr2C1": 447,
                    "Tr1CW1": 3,
                    "Tr2CW1": 9,
                    "Tr2CD1": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 54.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 133.4,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "South Australia",
                            "ID": "86297",
                            "Abr": "SOU"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "New South Wales",
                            "ID": "86293",
                            "Abr": "NEW"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 133,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 2",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "South Australia trail New South Wales by 313 runs with 7 wickets remaining",
                    "Ebat": 1,
                    "TPa": 1,
                    "TCho": 2,
                    "Esd": 20230314053000,
                    "Ese": 20230317053000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "723829",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "723829",
                        "12": "SBTE_28555867"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 122,
                    "Tr2C1": 298,
                    "Tr1C2": 88,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 3,
                    "Tr1CO1": 61.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 92.0,
                    "Tr1CO2": 28.0,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Western Australia",
                            "ID": "86294",
                            "Abr": "WES"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Victoria",
                            "ID": "86296",
                            "Abr": "VIC"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 133,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 2",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Western Australia trail Victoria by 88 runs with 7 wickets remaining",
                    "Ebat": 1,
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 2,
                    "Esd": 20230314073000,
                    "Ese": 20230317073000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "11476",
            "Snm": "Plunket Shield",
            "Scd": "plunket-shield",
            "Cnm": "New Zealand",
            "Csnm": "New Zealand",
            "Ccd": "new-zealand",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "778935",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "778935",
                        "12": "SBTE_28555788"
                    },
                    "Media": {
                        "12": [
                            {
                                "eventId": "2182599",
                                "provider": "PERFORM",
                                "type": "LIVE_STREAMING",
                                "allowedCountries": [
                                    "GB",
                                    "IE",
                                    "NL"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 186,
                    "Tr2C1": 282,
                    "Tr1C2": 103,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 68.3,
                    "Tr2CO1": 81.0,
                    "Tr1CO2": 35.0,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Canterbury",
                            "ID": "86322",
                            "Abr": "CAN"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Central Stags",
                            "ID": "86326",
                            "Abr": "CEN"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 134,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 3",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Canterbury lead Central Stags by 7 runs with 9 wickets remaining",
                    "Ebat": 1,
                    "TPa": 1,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230313030000,
                    "Ese": 20230316030000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "778931",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "778931"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 405,
                    "Tr2C1": 221,
                    "Tr1C2": 206,
                    "Tr2C2": 17,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 8,
                    "Tr2CW2": 1,
                    "Tr1CD2": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 88.1,
                    "Tr2CO1": 95.2,
                    "Tr1CO2": 41.0,
                    "Tr2CO2": 14.0,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Northern Districts",
                            "ID": "86323",
                            "Abr": "NOR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Wellington",
                            "ID": "86321",
                            "Abr": "WEL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 134,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 3",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Wellington Firebirds need 374 runs to win",
                    "Ebat": 2,
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 2,
                    "Esd": 20230313030000,
                    "Ese": 20230316030000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "778933",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "778933"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 454,
                    "Tr2C1": 351,
                    "Tr1CW1": 9,
                    "Tr2CW1": 9,
                    "Tr2CD1": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 170.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 116.0,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Otago",
                            "ID": "86319",
                            "Abr": "OTA"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Auckland",
                            "ID": "86320",
                            "Abr": "AUC"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 134,
                    "EpsL": "Stumps - day 3",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Otago Volts lead Auckland Aces by 103 runs with 1 wicket remaining",
                    "Ebat": 1,
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230313030000,
                    "Ese": 20230316030000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "12081",
            "Snm": "CSA Four-Day Series: Division 1",
            "Scd": "csa-four-day-series-division-1",
            "Cnm": "South Africa",
            "Csnm": "South Africa",
            "Ccd": "south-africa",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "827681",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "827681"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 259,
                    "Tr2C1": 329,
                    "Tr1C2": 265,
                    "Tr2C2": 222,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 7,
                    "Tr2CW2": 10,
                    "Tr1CO1": 105.0,
                    "Tr2CO1": 93.3,
                    "Tr1CO2": 87.1,
                    "Tr2CO2": 47.5,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "DP World Lions",
                            "ID": "86101",
                            "Abr": "DPW"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Dolphins",
                            "ID": "86097",
                            "Abr": "DOL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "",
                    "Esid": 33,
                    "EpsL": "Play in progress",
                    "Epr": 1,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Lions need 28 runs to win",
                    "Ebat": 1,
                    "TPa": 1,
                    "TCho": 2,
                    "Esd": 20230312130000,
                    "Ese": 20230315130000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816359,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "827678",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "827678"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 319,
                    "Tr2C1": 148,
                    "Tr1C2": 190,
                    "Tr2C2": 360,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 1,
                    "Tr2CW2": 10,
                    "Tr1CO1": 81.4,
                    "Tr2CO1": 56.2,
                    "Tr1CO2": 38.3,
                    "Tr2CO2": 94.4,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Titans",
                            "ID": "86099",
                            "Abr": "TIT"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "North West Dragons",
                            "ID": "188954",
                            "Abr": "NOR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "FT",
                    "Esid": 6,
                    "EpsL": "Finished",
                    "Epr": 2,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Titans win by 9 wickets",
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230312130000,
                    "Ese": 20230315130000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816357,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "827679",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "827679"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 198,
                    "Tr2C1": 352,
                    "Tr1C2": 259,
                    "Tr2C2": 184,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 10,
                    "Tr2CW2": 10,
                    "Tr1CO1": 75.2,
                    "Tr2CO1": 102.0,
                    "Tr1CO2": 71.4,
                    "Tr2CO2": 56.2,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Western Province",
                            "ID": "188949",
                            "Abr": "WES"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Warriors",
                            "ID": "86100",
                            "Abr": "WAR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "FT",
                    "Esid": 6,
                    "EpsL": "Finished",
                    "Epr": 2,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Warriors win by 79 runs",
                    "TPa": 2,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230312130000,
                    "Ese": 20230315130000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816357,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "827682",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "827682"
                    },
                    "Tr1C1": 212,
                    "Tr2C1": 493,
                    "Tr1C2": 319,
                    "Tr2C2": 39,
                    "Tr1CW1": 10,
                    "Tr2CW1": 10,
                    "Tr1CW2": 10,
                    "Tr2CW2": 1,
                    "Tr1CO1": 69.4,
                    "Tr2CO1": 132.0,
                    "Tr1CO2": 94.4,
                    "Tr2CO2": 6.1,
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Rocks",
                            "ID": "188956",
                            "Abr": "ROC"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Knights",
                            "ID": "86096",
                            "Abr": "KNI"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "FT",
                    "Esid": 6,
                    "EpsL": "Finished",
                    "Epr": 2,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Knights win by 9 wickets",
                    "TPa": 1,
                    "TCho": 1,
                    "Esd": 20230312133000,
                    "Ese": 20230315133000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 6816357,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "12941",
            "Snm": "West Indies Championship",
            "Scd": "west-indies-championship",
            "Cnm": "West Indies",
            "Csnm": "West Indies",
            "Ccd": "west-indies",
            "Scu": 0,
            "Events": [
                {
                    "Eid": "902100",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "902100"
                    },
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Jamaica Scorpions",
                            "ID": "133543",
                            "Abr": "JAM"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Windward Volcanoes",
                            "ID": "133541",
                            "Abr": "WIN"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "NS",
                    "Esid": 1,
                    "EpsL": "Not started",
                    "Epr": 0,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Teams will be announced at the toss",
                    "TPa": 0,
                    "TCho": 0,
                    "Esd": 20230315193000,
                    "Ese": 20230318193000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 524295,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "902103",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "902103"
                    },
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Leeward Islands Hurricanes",
                            "ID": "133540",
                            "Abr": "LEE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Barbados Pride",
                            "ID": "133545",
                            "Abr": "BAR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "NS",
                    "Esid": 1,
                    "EpsL": "Not started",
                    "Epr": 0,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Teams will be announced at the toss",
                    "TPa": 0,
                    "TCho": 0,
                    "Esd": 20230315193000,
                    "Ese": 20230318193000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 524295,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                },
                {
                    "Eid": "902099",
                    "Pids": {
                        "8": "902099"
                    },
                    "T1": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "T&T Red Force",
                            "ID": "133544",
                            "Abr": "T&T"
                        }
                    ],
                    "T2": [
                        {
                            "Nm": "Guyana Jaguars",
                            "ID": "133542",
                            "Abr": "GUY"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Eps": "NS",
                    "Esid": 1,
                    "EpsL": "Not started",
                    "Epr": 0,
                    "Ecov": 0,
                    "Et": 170,
                    "EtTx": "Domestic First Class",
                    "ECo": "Teams will be announced at the toss",
                    "TPa": 0,
                    "TCho": 0,
                    "Esd": 20230315193000,
                    "Ese": 20230318193000,
                    "Exd": 4,
                    "EO": 524295,
                    "Spid": 73,
                    "Pid": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

when the date in request is changed the structure would change
the change in the structure is taking place only in 'Stages' and 'Events'

I am accessing the events using "Stages[0]" "Stages[1]" etc and the events in the stages using "Events[0]" "Events[1]" but sometimes the "Events[1]" doesnt exist and iterating through all of that using different components is very time consuming

I am new in coding and I dont have good experience in this field so please a help would be thankful :)

Comment: What do you mean with 'changes structure'? Does the data 'model' itself change, or are there just less values present in the array?

Comment: I mean that sometimes the Events array contain only 1 list but sometimes it contains multiple lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, based on your comment you just want to loop over the values in `Events`. Your thinking is good using `Events[0]`, `Events[1]` etc but this won't work as its hardcoded. Instead you should loop over the object:

```js
const events = stages.map((obj) => obj.events); // gets all events
```

Now you can just do something with the events like you're currently doing:

```js
// render something
events.map((event) => {
   // do something with events
})
```

Some other source which might be useful for you:
[React loop over an object with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163521/react-loop-over-an-object-with-array)

Comment: Heyy thanks for quick replies and an answer this actually worked